# Transparent model when exporting fbx file to Unity

Tags: export, faces, normals, unity, .fbx

So I have this shark model which I animated and ready to export it on fbx and transport it to Unity.

But When I put it on Unity, It looks transparent like this.

[image]

Many of the solutions online say that the problem is because of my faces, and they told me to recalculate it or something, but normals are just fine.
Is there any other solution?

here's the blend file: [image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you apply your rotation/scale/location. With the shark selected in object mode. Ctrl-A Location and Rotation/Scale before exporting

Comment: Thx! everything worked afterwards! after I applied all my location/rotation/scale, suddenly my object's faces flipped and then I recalculated it. after that when I import it to Unity, it's not invisible anymore.